# Can't get all rows in MySQL database using Volley

Tags: java, android

I have try to get all row in table in MySQL database and it' working well but when new row insert the application don't update the response but in web browsers is update

```
 private void connect() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, GET_ALL_PHRASES_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                  Log.d("response","the response : " + response);

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("response","the response error : " + error);

                }
            });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

the response in android studio log-cat 
{"phrase":[{"id":"id_1"},{"id":"Id_2"},{"id":"id_3"},{"id":"id_5"}],"success":1}

and the response in web browser is
{"phrase":[{"id":"id_1"},{"id":"Id_2"},{"id":"id_3"},{"id":"id_5"},{"id":"id_6"},{"id":"id_7"}],"success":1}

my question is why the response is update in web and in android didn't up date but when i clear cash it update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling the Volley cache and see if that helps.

```
stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
requestQueue.add(request);
```

If the above doesn't work, you might want to try

```
requestQueue.getCache().clear();
requestQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: is there any another way to solve that problem without clear cache